# Unable to route properly with bidi

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, bidi

I am sending an index-handler on "/this-route":

```
(defn index-handler [req]
  (assoc (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"})
         :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}))

(def routes ["" {"/this-route" {:get index-handler}}]) ;; works
```

Which works fine.

But when I append anything to this-route, I'm unable to send index-handler even though I can still send a basic res/response:

```
(def routes ["" {"/this-route" {"" {:get index-handler} ;; doesn't work
                                "/something" {:get index-handler} ;; doesn't work
                                "/something-else" (res/response "some response") ;; works  

}}])
```

I get the errors in the client side console showing an error in the index.html line, where I start my app:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">myapp.system.go();</script>
```

and the error is "myapp is not defined."

Why might this be, and what am I doing wrong?

--- EDIT ---
This is the complete error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myapp is not defined
    at something-else:15

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: If you client side JS no longer works, you most likely changed the routes the JS files no longer can load? Do you see 404s in your dev console/network tab? If that's the case, please rewrite the last bit of the question to make that clear.

Comment: yes I do. Complete output in edit.

Comment: What I meant is: do you see 404 errors in the _network_ tab?  Can your compiled output (the .js files) no longer be loaded?

Comment: There's a "something" name which returns 200 in the network tab. No 404s. I have four things in network tab with something 200, style.css 204, myapp.js 204 and favicon.png 204.

Comment: And if you go back to the "just works" version this error goes away and everything is fine?

Comment: I don't know how to go back to the "just works" version.

Comment: This is my gut feeling here: the action and the effect do not match. You changed things, you got the myapp error and you attributed it to the route change - but I can not imagine how they fit together unless you changed the routes in a way, you no longer can load the generated .js files. So I'd go back to square one and create a new project and just isolate this problem. If you have version control, bisect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes work fine:

```
  (let [routes ["" {"/this-route" {:get :some-handler}}]]
    (is= (bidi/match-route routes "/this-route" :request-method :get)
      {:handler :some-handler, :request-method :get}))

  (let [routes ["" {"/this-route" {""                {:get :handler-1}
                                   "/something"      {:get :handler-2}
                                   "/something-else" {:get :handler-3}}}]]
    (is= (bidi/match-route routes "/this-route" :request-method :get)
      {:handler :handler-1, :request-method :get})
    (is= (bidi/match-route routes "/this-route/something" :request-method :get)
      {:handler :handler-2, :request-method :get})
    (is= (bidi/match-route routes "/this-route/something-else" :request-method :get)
      {:handler :handler-3, :request-method :get}))
```

As cfrick said, you have somehow created a problem compiling and/or loading your code.  That is where you need to look.